# Tag Suggestions for Star Trek The Next Generation

Tags: discussion, tags

Right now this site uses the tag `star-trek-next-generation`, while the [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-tng) site uses the tag `star-trek-tng`.

There is a synonym that maps `star-trek-tng` to `star-trek-next-generation`, so everything works okay in practice. But I think it could be better.

**Could we make** `star-trek-tng` **the master tag instead?**

---

It's also a little strange that the word "the" is missing from `star-trek-next-generation`). If that's going to remain the master tag, I think it should be fixed.

(If `star-trek-tng`, becomes the master tag, this won't really matter.)

Comment: Why to go for abbreviation when we can go for full name O.o

Comment: the only reason would be to match the Sci-Fi site. I'm okay with full name though - as long as we fix it (full means "the" is in the name)

Comment: "The" was not there as in past the limit was 25 character for tag. And we don't have to do inter-site tag standardization and sci-fi site prefer abbreviation more then us and changing all of our tags according to them make no sense.

Comment: I have added "the" for now, rest will wait for other responses .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Make [star-trek-the-next-generation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-the-next-generation) the master, and make [star-trek-tng](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-tng) a synonym.

The official name of the series is *Star Trek: The Next Generation*. The tag was created as [star-trek-next-generation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-next-generation) because the character limit for tags was capped at 25. Now that we can use 35 characters, it makes sense to expand to the full name.

Using the full name is good because if someone types `star-trek-the-n` into the tag box, we want the right tag to be suggested.

This is also why making [star-trek-tng](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-tng) a synonym is a good idea. The series is referred to as "TNG" in many places, and if someone types `star-trek-tng` into the tag box, we want the correct tag to be used.

Comment: Yeah, not a fan of acronyms, they always come with a certain "in-crowd" by-taste. The primary tag should be as understandable as possible. As a synonym it's okay, though.